# Why is Jacob so harsh in saying “Why do you just keep looking at each other?” in Genesis 42:1?

Tags: genesis

New International Version
Genesis 42:

> 1
> When Jacob learned that there was grain in Egypt, he said to his sons, “Why do you **just keep** looking at each other?” 2He continued, “I have heard that there is grain in Egypt. Go down there and buy some for us, so that we may live and not die.”
>
> 3Then ten of Joseph’s brothers went down to buy grain from Egypt. 4But Jacob did not send Benjamin, Joseph’s brother, with the others, because he was afraid that harm might come to him. 5So Israel’s sons were among those who went to buy grain, for there was famine in the land of Canaan also.

“Why do you just keep looking at each other?”

Jacob seems to begin this request in an unusually harsh way - I would expect him to be a bit friendlier when he was about to make a request of his sons. Why was he so harsh on them here? Was he belittling his own sons? Was he frustrated by them? by the famine?

Comment: See also Acts 1:11. It is a call to action.

Comment: Yes, that's better than my original. I was still making the mistake to expect people should read all my little questions neutrally. The fact is that even a little question contains imports. Your restating some of my little questions as positive facts would do away with the opinionated imports. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

#### *Why is Jacob so harsh [to his sons] in Genesis 42:1?*

Answer: **A very concerned father is merely conveying his worry and frustration to his (often very wayward) sons**.

Ellicott seems to have captured the substance of this encounter well:

> "[Not] only would the flocks and herds begin to languish, but the numerous retainers of Jacob and his sons would also become enfeebled from insufficient nourishment, and begin to die of low fever and those other diseases which follow in the train of famine. Jacob's words, therefore, mean, **Why are you irresolute, and uncertain what to do?** And then he encourages them to take this journey as a possible means of providing for the wants of their households.

Another take on this from the Pulpit commentary reads:

> "'Why do ye look one upon another?' [That is,] in such a helpless and undecided manner (Keil)."

Modern terminology might read, "Hey bozos, what are you all standing around staring at? We need food now — go get some!"

Comment: Good answer +1.